# how to call module functions on functions

Tags: python, python-2.7

Maybe this is a silly question but I am struggling with it and I can't manage to find a clear explanation on the internet.

So I want to write a module with a function in it. I would like this function to take another function as argument, do something to the output of the argument-function and return it.

In code what I would like to do is:

```
from my_module import my_function  

output = stuff.my_function()  # stuff = what my_function accepts as   argument
```

Since there are many in build python methods that do this I believe it is possible but I have no idea how. I tried a few ways but none work.

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: that is why we have decorators in python, read about them here http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/ you will get an idea

Comment: function decorators do not really address the much simpler question of just passing a function as an arg.

Comment: I know how to do function(another_function). what I am asking is how to use the .funcion notation.  e.g.  foo.strip(), my_file.read() etc. I apologize if I was not clear in the first place.

Comment: You may need to look at `class`es. That notation is for calling scoped objects. Modules also provide scope so you could `import my_module` then calling `my_function` would be `my_module.my_function`. Why do you care about the dot notation?

Comment: You want `a_function.my_function()` to have the same effect as `a_function(my_function())`?

Comment: Yes, and I also would like to be able to pass to my_funcion other stuff. For example word = "a word"   word.my_function().

Comment: @Faber You can'd do that, you can't add new attributes to a `str` object.

Answer (score 4):

Functions are first class citizen's in python so you pass functions by name without the `()`, then you can call that function by using the `()` e.g.:

```
from my_module import my_function  

def a_function(x):
    y = x()
    return y

output = a_function(my_function)
```

Comment: and what if instead of a function a want it to be a script (a .py file)? Is the same concept?

Comment: executing a whole script is not quite the same... when you import `my_module` it will run all of the code in `my_module.py` which are usually just `def`initions of functions but if there is any bare code it will be executed. You can dynamically import a `.py` but that is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is pass `a_function` as an argument to `my_function` and get a modified function back.

Here's a simple example:

```
In [1]: def add_one(f):
   ...:     def f_plus_1(*args, **kwargs):
   ...:         return f(*args, **kwargs) + 1
   ...:     return f_plus_1
   ...: 

In [2]: def multiply(a, b):
   ...:     return a * b
   ...: 

In [3]: multiply_and_add_one = add_one(multiply)

In [4]: multiply(5, 3)
Out[4]: 15

In [5]: multiply_and_add_one(5, 3)
Out[5]: 16
```

Here we use `*args` and `**kwargs` to pass through any arguments we get to the original function.

Answer (score 0):

file my_module.py

```
def my_function():
    return something
```

file current.py

```
from my_module import my_function

def a_function(x):
    does something 
    return y

output = a_function(my_function())
```